# How to organize multiple electrical wires going into an ultra thin recessed light?

Tags: electrical, wiring, recessed-lighting, junction-box

I am installing ultra thin recessed light in the basement and it comes with a very small metal box (probably 2x4 in in size). Due to the old wiring of the house, there are 5 wires coming in totally: power to light 1, power to light 2, 2 switches, and the light itself. It's going to be very "crowded" because the wire nut will have to fit like 4-5 wires.

I would like to "connect" everything" outside of the ultra thin metal box and only leave 3 wires (white, black, ground) coming into the box itself.

I am thinking of a few options:

1. Use an electrical box and connect everything in there but leave 3 wires out to go into the recessed box. Then close the box with a lid and just sort of "throw" it up in the ceiling somewhere (no screw or mount into joists).
2. Tear up the ceiling to find a joist and install a Round Hard-Shell Ceiling Box then connect everything there. However, the hard part is to connect existing wiring since some are not long enough. I may have to create additional lumber support. Either that or I have to use the ceiling box that has a metal bar to mount both joists. Regardless, this is major ceiling work and drywall fixes.

I am leaning toward **Option 1** as I doubt there is any unforeseen issue. What are your thoughts?

Reference: the light I bought is

[image]

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B079GLKCV7/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B079GLKCV7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Use an old work box to house the splices

There's a simple way out of this, and that's to use an *old work box* mounted into the ceiling drywall to house the electrical splices.  A 3 gang switch box will do the trick, or you can use a 4 11/16" square box that's 1.5" or deeper if you can get an old work mountable version of that.  (Really, anything that supplies more than 29.5 in3 of space will do.)